# yet another QMAKE_CXXFLAGS issue

Tags: g++, qmake, compiler-flags

I'm tryng to pass a flag to g++ so I added `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x` to my *.pro file, but it seems not to get accepted. It also doesn't get colored in the QtCreator as do other variable (like `SOURCES` for example).

I trying to use `nullptr` in this case and the code can be compiled and run via the command line. When using QtCreator I get `nullptr was not declared in this scope`.

Any idea on what I may be missing?

Comment: Which platform are you working on?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.10. Sorry, forgot to mention.

Answer (score 0):

that is because qt-creator is actually using the stock gcc from apple (4.2.1) instead of the one you actually selected (after installing it via ports). e.g. you install g++-mp-4.6.1 and add the tool chain, so far so good, if you go back to project settings, you will notice that the ide actually restricts the toolsets selection to the default ones (regrettable bug!)